# Android facebook Status on sharing complete or not

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am using latest Facebook SDK for sharing link. I am using standard code that is given in the tutorial. But so far I am unable to know the status of post.
i.e. whether user posts through Facebook dialog or cancelled it I always receive null/same values.

As it is important part of my application logic. I want to know whether user really posted or not.

Code I am using in activity result:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("hariss",resultCode+"");
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");

           //tried various things here to know weather user posted or not, but failed

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you also using Facebook login? You will only know the status if the user has logged in via FB from your app, this is by design.

Comment: Oh that means if user didn't logged in we cannot get status of sharing?

Comment: Correct. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkshare-handlingresponses

Comment: so basically u r question is sharing link ? or shared successfully and becoz of some issue it isnt should status? and wanna undesrtand what u wanna do this posted status?

Comment: it is kind of my App's functionality, on sharing a link on facebook, he will be awarded something.
I want status that after opening facebook share dialog, user really posted something or cancelled it.

Comment: did you open the sessions on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method for posting and you can do the later task in onComplete method.

```
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override //enter code here
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```